# Is there a more elegant way to select between max or min method from a stream?

Tags: java, java-8, java-stream

I want to get a min or max item from a list according to some condition.
The snippet bellow summarizes what I doing:

```
Optional<Person> target;
if(condition){
    target = detailedList.stream().min((d1, d2) -> d1.age() + d2.age());
} else {
    target = detailedList.stream().max((d1, d2) -> d1.age() + d2.age());
}
```

It works but is quite verbose. In essence I want to select either the method **min** or **max** in the stream. Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Do you mean `d1.age() - d2.age()`?

Answer (score 8):

Here's another way:

```
Comparator<Person> comp = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::age);
BinaryOperator<Person> op 
    = condition ? BinaryOperator.minBy(comp) : BinaryOperator.maxBy(comp);

Optional<Person> target = list.stream().reduce(op);
```

Answer (score 4):

I would suggest the method that makes your intent clearest is:

```
Comparator<Person> ageComparator = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::age);
Optional<Person> target = condition ? 
    list.stream().min(ageComparator) : list.stream().max(ageComparator);
```

Comment: I like all the "clever" alternatives suggested, but I think this is how I would actually do it.

Answer (score 2):

You could do this:

```
Comparator<Person> c = Comparator.comparingInt(Person::age);
Optional<Person> target = detailedList.stream().min(condition ? c : c.reversed());
```

It's shorter, but personally I think combining `min` with `reversed` to find the maximum is a bit of a hack. I would stick to the original.

Answer (score 1):

Another solution would be to calculate both the min and the max with the same collecting step. For that, we can inspire ourselves from the [`IntSummaryStatistics`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/IntSummaryStatistics.html) class and construct a `ObjectSummaryStatistics` which would hold the min and max values.

This solution is probably too much for your particular use-case. It might be handy only if you find yourself doing this a lot.

The min and max are initialized to `null` and are updated each time an element is accepted or a combine is made. I used `Optional`s as return value to be consistent with what the API returns for the common `min` and `max` operations.

```
public class ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> implements Consumer<T> {

    private long count;
    private T min;
    private T max;
    private Comparator<T> comparator;

    public ObjectSummaryStatistics(Comparator<T> comparator) {
        this.comparator = Objects.requireNonNull(comparator, "A comparator must be set");
    }

    @Override
    public void accept(T t) {
        min = count == 0 ? t : min(min, t);
        max = count == 0 ? t : max(max, t);
        count++;
    }

    public void combine(ObjectSummaryStatistics<T> other) {
        if (other.comparator != comparator) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Can't combine with a summary statistics having a different comparator");
        }
        if (count == 0) {
            min = other.min;
            max = other.max;
        } else if (other.count > 0) {
            min = min(min, other.min);
            max = max(max, other.max);
        }
        count += other.count;
    }

    public Optional<T> getMin() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(min);
    }

    public Optional<T> getMax() {
        return Optional.ofNullable(max);
    }

    public long getCount() {
        return count;
    }

    private T min(T t1, T t2) {
        return comparator.compare(t1, t2) <= 0 ? t1 : t2;
    }

    private T max(T t1, T t2) {
        return comparator.compare(t1, t2) >= 0 ? t1 : t2;
    }

}
```

Then you could construct a `Collector` that would collect to this class:

```
public static <T> Collector<T, ?, ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>> summarizing(Comparator<T> comparator) {
    return Collector.of(
                () -> new ObjectSummaryStatistics<T>(comparator), 
                ObjectSummaryStatistics::accept,
                (s1, s2) -> { s1.combine(s2); return s1; }
           );
}
```

Finally, your code becomes:

```
ObjectSummaryStatistics<Person> s = detailedList.stream().collect(summarizing((d1, d2) -> d1.age() + d2.age()));
System.out.println(s.getMin());
System.out.println(s.getMax());
```

*Side-note: the Comparator you have in your question is not transitive so it won't work as-is*